# All text files appear corrupted

Tags: windows-10, file-corruption

Opening all documents I've checked so far results in a jumbled mess of characters as shown in the screenshot below (I would copy and paste, but that has also stopped working)
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sz5ot.png)

Onedrive backup set up for all of the documents. However strangely enough when I check the files on onedrive they appear file (they're definitely sync'd). Also when I download the files from onedrive to try and replace the corrupted ones on the computer, then they also appear corrupted. It's as if something has taken over how the user reads files and is scrambling it when it's opened.

I've run a malwarebytes scan, I'm unsure what else to do though. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: To confirm, is this affecting all documents, or only OneDrive?

Comment: Scratch that, onedrive files now appear to be affected too as well as those on the computer

Comment: Are the file names corrupted as well? This could help narrow down what/if crypto malware is involved.

Comment: No the file names are fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be some type of crypto malware at first glance. There are methods of removal and recovery available, but there are many variants of such malware. I would suggest to stop using your computer immediately and have the hard drive serviced by an experienced IT repair professional.

You may be able to recover older versions of your files in OneDrive that are not corrupted following [these steps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Restore-a-previous-version-of-a-file-in-OneDrive-159cad6d-d76e-4981-88ef-de6e96c93893) provided by Microsoft.

Comment: I don't believe it was malware, I think onedrive did something weird to the files because it couldn't understand the format. Restoring the files from point in time sorted out the encryption, and copy and paste started working after a restart.

Comment: Bizarre. I have not run into OneDrive file corruption in some time. Please reopen your question if it does reoccur.